# Dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu on SD card EFI (Chuwi VI10)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, flash, sd-card

I have bought a Chuwi VI10, very cheap chinese computer dual booting Windows 8.1 and Android. It runs InsydeH2O BIOS. I got rid of the Android stuff and decided I wanted to install Ubuntu on the SD-card and dual boot between Ubuntu and Windows 8.1. The main flash is too small to house both Windows and Ubuntu.

I manage to boot from a Ubuntu USB key without problem and I have verified that I have booted via EFI since `/sys/firmware/efi` exists.

Installation to the SD card (`/dev/mmcblk1`) works fine and EFI files are correctly added to `/dev/mmcblk0p1/EFI`.

I have also checked the EFI table using `efibootmgr -v`

```
...
Boot0007* Ubuntu    HD(1,800,32000,89b680e5-c76a-48cf-b16f-eb7733137551)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
...
```

The item shows up in the EFI boot menu but if I select it it just boots Windows. Any way to debug why it is doing this?

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that disabling Secure Boot will fix the problem, but that's a bit of a long shot, since I'd expect that a problem that affected the installed system would also affect the installation media. Unfortunately, no two computers are exactly alike when it comes to Secure Boot settings, so it's impossible to completely describe how to try this; but I show several examples on [my page on Secure Boot.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable)

A more likely possibility is that you've got a defective firmware that ignores its boot settings. The best solution to this problem is to obtain a fixed firmware from your manufacturer. Unfortunately, few manufacturers ever bother to fix this type of problem, but it's worth looking for an updated firmware. (The manufacturer is likely to call it a "BIOS," although it really isn't a BIOS.) If that fails, you could try working around this by using [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) You'll need to go to the Advanced menu and select the option to back up and rename the boot loader files. If *that* fails, then be sure to undo the operation with Boot Repair, since the moved and renamed files will just complicate the boot path and make future changes more complex.

Comment: I have checked the BIOS utility and secure boot is already disabled. Is there any way I can check the boot settings ?